# Can't set origin on github repo

Tags: git, github

I'm a newish git and GitHub user. I've been using GitHub for windows for a while but wanted to try more of the command line while learning how to fork and submit pull requests on a repo I want to improve.

What I'm seeing is that 'upstream' seems to be defined by unusable and I want to understand what's going on. I imagine that this will be a problem for when I want to request that my changes get pulled into the upstream repository.

---

I forked [the repository](https://github.com/vanpop/CPT-Descriptions) on GitHub and then cloned it to my computer:

`git clone https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions.git`

I then entered the new repository and tried to add the upstream as listed on the [Forking Tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo):

`git remote add upstream https://github.com/vanpop/CPT-Descriptions.git`

That gives me the error:

> fatal: remote upstream already exists.

When I try: `git fetch upstream`, I get this:

> fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: could not read remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I've read other threads that suggest editing my git config file but there's no mention of upstream in it:

> [core]
>
> repositoryformatversion = 0
>
> filemode = false
>
> bare = false
>
> logallrefupdates = true
>
> symlinks = false
>
> ignorecase = true
>
> hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
>
> [remote "origin"]
>
> url = https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions.git
>
> fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>
> [branch "master"]
>
> remote = origin
>
> merge = refs/heads/master

Finally, when I try `git remote -v` I get this:

> origin   https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions.git (fetch)
>
> origin   https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions.git (push)
>
> upstream

=======================

UPDATE: Adding the results of `git config -l`:

> core.symlinks=false core.autocrlf=true core.editor=gitpad
>
> color.diff=auto color.status=auto color.branch=auto
>
> color.interactive=true color.ui=true pack.packsizelimit=2g
>
> help.format=html http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
>
> sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
>
> diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain rebase.autosquash=true
>
> credential.helper=!github --credentials filter.ghcleansmudge.clean=cat
>
> filter.ghcleansmudge.smudge=cat push.default=upstream
>
> alias.dt=difftool alias.mt=mergetool diff.tool=vs11
>
> difftool.prompt=false difftool.bc4.cmd="c:/program files (x86)/beyond
>
> compare 3/bcomp.exe" "$LOCAL" "$ REMOTE" difftool.p4.cmd="c:/program
>
> files/Perforce/p4merge.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
>
> difftool.vs11.cmd="c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio
>
> 11.0/common7/i de/devenv.exe" '//diff' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" merge.tool=bc3 
>   mergetool.prompt=false mergetool.keepbackup=false
>
> mergetool.bc3.cmd="c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe"
>
> "$LOCAL" " $REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED" mergetool.bc3.trustexitcode=true
>
> mergetool.p4.cmd="c:/program files/Perforce/p4merge.exe" "$BASE"
>
> "$LOCAL" "$REMO TE" "$MERGED" mergetool.p4.trustexitcode=false
>
> remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>
> remote.origin.fetch=+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
>
> remote.upstream.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
>
> remote.upstream.fetch=+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*
>
> user.name=mrwweb user.email=info@mrwweb.com core.autocrlf=true
>
> core.repositoryformatversion=0 core.filemode=false core.bare=false
>
> core.logallrefupdates=true core.symlinks=false core.ignorecase=true
>
> core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
>
> remote.origin.url=https://github.com/mrwweb/CPT-Descriptions.git
>
> remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>
> branch.master.remote=origin branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trouble-shooting (thank you @alex_sf) I believe the problem is GitHub for Windows. I was using the posh~git shell provided with GitHub for Windows, and one of those two things had set up the global config for my environment.

After going back to GitHub for Windows' own documentation, I found this:

> GitHub for Windows does not support multiple Git remotes and it will only work with the origin remote.

I think that explains it :(

Comment: Multiple remotes should be possible with the shell. Try a different name for the upstream, e.g. upstream2. git remote add upstream2 origin

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me.  Somehow you have a blank upstream remote.

Run this in the git directory:

```
git remote rm upstream
```

Then add the upstream again:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/vanpop/CPT-Descriptions.git
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried that and got: "error: could not remove config section 'remote.upstream'". As you can see in my question, that section doesn't seem to be in the config file at all...

Comment: This is really weird, there should be an entry for upstream in .git/config.  Try to fork another repo and add an upstream to ensure this isn't a global git issue for you.  If another repo works fine, trash the original forked repo and refork it.

Comment: If another repo fails similarly, you have a bad config in your global git config.  If you are on Windows 7, the global config is located at C:\Users\<username\.gitconfig.  There may be an entry in there labelled "upstream" that you should remove.

Comment: Good and bad news. Another repo failed so it seems to be something on my end. However, that global config only has my username, email, and "[core] autocrlf = true."

Comment: Does 'git config --global --edit' give you that same config file or a different one?

Comment: Also, please go into the project directory and add the output of "git config -l" to your question, might see it in there.

Comment: Ok, we've got an upstream now, but it's got no URL specified.  There's a janky config somewhere, and it looks like you've got a good bit of git customization going on.  I can't tell you specifically where this is at with the modifications you've made.  You'll need to do a search on your system for a file containing "refs/remotes/upstream/" that would be affecting that repo.